# Is there a way to make a grid area behave like flexbox?

Tags: css, css-grid

Say I have an arbitrary number of elements at the same level:

```
    <container>
        <div class="h">
        <div class="b">
        <div class="h">
        <div class="h">
        <div class="b">
        <div class="hl">
        <div class="hr">
        <div class="hl">
        <div class="hr">
        <div class="h">
        <div class="f">
    </container>
```

And I want a layout that's something like

```
    grid-template-area:
        "h  h"
        "hl hr"
        "b  b"
        "f  f"
```

I can put everything in the right spot with `grid-area`, but then everything just gets stacked along the z access. So, the two ways I'm thinking about this are either:

1. is there a way to define a named grid area to behave like a flexbox? Something like, in pseudocode:

   define grid area h: display: flex; flex-direction: column;

or 2) make each named area have auto rows? So, if I

```
.h {
    grid-area: h;
}
```

and I have 3 `divs` with class h, it implies

```
    grid-template-area:
        "h  h"
        "h  h"
        "h  h"
        "hl hr"
        "b  b"
        "f  f"
```

Or maybe there's some other idea I haven't thought of to accomplish this layout?

Code Snippet:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "h  h" "h  h" "h  h" "hl hr" "b  b" "f  f"
}

.h {
  grid-area: h;
}

.hl {
  grid-area: hl;
}

.hr {
  grid-area: hr;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
}

.f {
  grid-area: f;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="h">h1</div>
  <div class="b">b1</div>
  <div class="h">h2</div>
  <div class="h">h3</div>
  <div class="b">b2</div>
  <div class="hl">hl1</div>
  <div class="hr">hr1</div>
  <div class="hl">hl2</div>
  <div class="hr">hr2</div>
  <div class="h">h3</div>
  <div class="f">f1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like not, but, like an option, you can change order of cells by using `order: n` property and define cell sizes to fit your layout, see:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  /*grid-template-areas: "h  h" "h  h" "h  h" "hl hr" "b  b" "f  f"*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: .1rem;
}

.container > div {
  padding: .25rem;
  border: .05rem solid;
}

.h {
  /*grid-area: h;*/
  order: 1;
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}

.hl {
  /*grid-area: hl;*/
  order: 2;
}

.hr {
  /*grid-area: hr;*/
  order: 3;
}

.b {
  /*grid-area: b;*/
  order: 4;
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}

.f {
  /*grid-area: f;*/
  order: 5;
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="h">h1</div>
  <div class="b">b1</div>
  <div class="h">h2</div>
  <div class="h">h3</div>
  <div class="b">b2</div>
  <div class="hl">hl1</div>
  <div class="hr">hr1</div>
  <div class="hl">hl2</div>
  <div class="hr">hr2</div>
  <div class="h">h4</div>
  <div class="f">f1</div>
</div>
```